# Unwanted tabulation in Kile editor after pressing Return

Tags: indentation, kile

I'm using Kile to edit LaTeX code.

When I press Return to get a new line, Kile does create a new line but automatically adds a tabulation (an indentation) at the beginning of the new line. This happens regardless of whethere there are trailing spaces after the cursor when I press Return.

This is quite annoying (especially when I paste things, it adds additional tabs, and I end up with a pyramid of indents...)

I have tried to change the indentation mode to "None" (and other values e.g. Python) to no avail. Any suggestions on the options I should look at? I tried a lot of them, but I'm not sure which one is the correct one. (Or could it be a bug?)

Comment: I cross-posted this on Stack Exchange. I hope it's not bad manners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it's a bit tricky. Go to Settings > Configure Kile; under Editor > Open/Save > Modes & Filetypes, change "Indentation Mode" to None. Then you have to close Kile, and when reopen, in a new file, there will be no auto-indentation.

Comment: Thank you. Does this mean that for files I've already worked on, I'm stuck with the auto-indentation?

Comment: Ha! It seems to work on old files too (after relaunch). Thanks!!